# Changing html tag style property On ajax success

Tags: html, ajax

I am trying to change the property of `div` if my ajax call returns success. but I can't find a way to do it.

Here is my Ajax success function, the first line of `.HTML()` works perfectly but the second line to style the display property doesn't work properly.

```
success:function(data){
  container.HTML(data.HTML);
  container.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `container`? Please edit your question to show all relevant code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `html()` method is in jQuery but your second line is for the DOM JavaScript. Did u try this?:

```
container.css("display": "block");
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. i dont know much about DOM. but for now u solved my problem :)